# Server-Side execute text command in another running program

Tags: php, command, server-side, whitelist

Question may seem a bit vague at first, but this is the part where I can explain in detail.

I have a system with a web page written in PHP (http://hawkserv.co.uk/servers.php). On this page, there is a section for specific whitelisting of users onto a game server. Through internal code, the PHP will check the user's name against other things (if they've joined the public server, how long ago, what rank they are, if they're banned, etc) and will add them to a text file which the game server, constantly running can read it.

The issue lies in that the program doesn't read it when it changes. It needs to be issued a command to tell it to read the file again. The command is "whitelist reload", and is input through a CMD window relating to the game server.

Is there any method in PHP or otherwise where I can issue the aforementioned command each time the whitelist file is updated with a new addition? Or am I out of luck with this? This ideally needs to be within the page, or at least referenced to something else that I can make and use.

Comment: `exec('whitelist reload');`

Comment: @Dagon How does exec() know what process to send that command to? The game server is not part of PHP, it's a separate running process. It's already running, and cannot be closed.

Comment: that's the equivalent of typing "whitelist reload" on the command line when logged in as php\Apache

Comment: But it doesn't define *which* command line to use. There is a completely separate command line not related to PHP in any way, and not referenced in Windows. I'm looking for a way to make it issue a command to a specific existing process, not a new one.

Comment: if its not the OS command line, you shouldn't be calling it the command line, its something else like an interactive shell.